# How can I transform multiple variations of the same data into one format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have read-only access to a database where I need to pull data from.

One of the columns is for social security numbers(US). The data is not formatted correctly and I am dealing with entries like:

- 123-45-0000
- 123 45 0000
- 123450000
- 123-45 0000
- 123 45-0000
- 123,45-0000
- 123-450000
- 12345-0000
- 123,45,0000
- 123,45,0000,

Our system needs the **SSN** to look like this: `123-45-0000`

I was able to figure out how to properly format the 3rd one(123450000) with this:

```
DECLARE @ssn CHAR(12) = 123450000
SELECT stuff(stuff(@ssn, 4, 0, '-'), 7, 0, '-') AS Social_Security_Number
```

But is there a way to fit all these other ones into the proper format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop worrying about which ones meet your formatting criteria, which ones are close, and how many different ways they're wrong. Just strip the formatting altogether and store numeric only; apply the formatting elsewhere. Much easier to constrain, too.

```
-- numeric only:

SELECT 
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(garbage,'-',' '),',',' '),' ','')
FROM dbo.SSNs;

-- with formatting added back:

SELECT STUFF(STUFF(
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(garbage,'-',' '),',',' '),' ',''),
  4,0,'-'),7,0,'-')
FROM dbo.SSNs;
```

Working example [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ypDGpWl2).

Once you've fixed the existing data, add a constraint that says something like `LEN(SSN) = 9 AND SSN NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` - strip any non-digits from the input on the way in, fail any write that doesn't do that, and apply the dashes - which are presentation only - in the UI (or in a view or a computed column if it can't be where it belongs).

Comment: Wow that's really amazing! So what you are doing, is just taking out all the "bad" parts, and leaving only the social security numbers, then you put the formatting back in?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Right, there's no reason to worry about "well what about this case when there's a comma at position 4, and this other case when there's a comma at position 5, and this other case when there's a dash in the wrong spot" - bah, that's all garbage. Just eliminate it all, it's way easier. And you don't _want_ to put the formatting back in, was the salient point I'm trying to make. Why do you need dashes _anywhere_ in the raw value stored in the database

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! The system that uses this, is kind of old and needs the data to be in a certain format.  The devs are aware though and hopefully will fix that.